# Matrix A of shape (5, 9) or with shape(5, 9)?

Tags: terminology, mathematics

When a matrix has a shape (5, 9), is it `of` shape(5, 9) or `with` shape(5,9)?

As the shape is an attribute of the matrix, I suppose it is `with`? Or something else e.g. `having`?

Which one is appropriate?

1. a matrix of shape (5, 9)
2. a matrix with shape (5, 9)
3. a matrix having shape (5, 9)
4. Else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be on-topic here; it might be on-topic on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com).

[One question there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746512) indicates that *of* is acceptable:

> Consider a matrix, **A,** of shape *m × n*.

However, both the other options are entirely understandable, and grammatical.

Comment: Using *with* is perfectly acceptable, too, at least going by [Mathematics Stackexchange Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615927/3d-array-multiplication). (And as a mathematician, I can't decide which of these two is better.)

Comment: Thanks, Peter. By all means as that as an answer.